# Order by sobre um Count em outra tabela

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Queria ordenar uma tabela de itens contando as avaliações(outra tabela) positivas referentes aquele item. Essa query será executada no *controler*: item *action*: index

```
Item:
  id
  nome

Avaliacao
  id
  item_id
  avaliacao[0 negativo, 1 positivo]
```

Por exemplo:

```
Banda 1 - <15 positivos> <3 negativos>
Banda 2 - <10 positivos> <30 negativos>
Banda 3 - <5 positiva> <0 negativas>
Banda 4 - <0 positiva> <0 negativas>
Banda 5 - <0 positiva> <0 negativas>
Banda 6 - <0 positiva> <0 negativas>
Banda 7 - <0 positiva> <0 negativas>
...
```

Answer (score 2):

Aproveitando a resposta do @bfavaretto, caso você tenha no `Avaliacao` um `belongs_to :item`, você deverá fazer o seguinte para o [ruby-on-rails](/questions/tagged/ruby-on-rails):

```ruby
Item.joins(:avaliacaos).group("avaliacaos.item_id").order("sum(avaliacaos.avaliacao) desc")
```

Caso contrário, será necessário iterar sobre os elementos do modelo `Item`

```ruby
items = Hash.new
Item.all.each do |item|
  items[item.id] = Avaliacao.where('item_id = ? AND avaliacao = ?', item.id, 1).count
end
maiores_avaliacoes = items.sort_by { |k,v| v}.reverse
```

Onde `maiores_avaliacoes` será um vetor de pares em que o primeiro elemento é a chave e o segundo o número de avaliações positivas, ou seja, o `maiores_avaliacoes[0]` retornará um vetor com duas posições onde a *posição 0* será o `item_id` do item com mais avaliações positivas e a *posição 1* será o **número de avaliações positivas** que tem aquele item.

Isso deverá retornar só os itens com avaliações e que sejam positivas.

---

## Como contar o número de avaliações positivas e negativas

Devido a minha inabilidade com consultas `SQL`, não saberei a consulta que deve ser feita para retornar o número de avaliações positivas ou negativas (apesar de supor que deva-se utilizar o `count` ao invés do `sum`). No entanto, é possível alcançar o que você deseja modificando um pouco o segundo exemplo, da seguinte forma:

```ruby
avaliacoes = Hash.new
Item.all.each do |item|
  avaliacoes[item.id] = [Avaliacao.where('item_id = ? AND avaliacao = ?', item.id, 0).count, Avaliacao.where('item_id = ? AND avaliacao = ?', item.id, 1).count]
end
Item.all.each do |item|
  puts item.nome + " - <" + avaliacoes[item.id][1] + " positivas> <" + avaliacoes[item.id][1] + " negativas>\n"
end
```

Isso imprime no console os dados da forma que você deseja, lembrando que o índice 1 contabiliza o número de avaliações **positivas**, enquanto o índice 0 contabiliza o número de avaliações **negativas**, salvando-os em uma `Hash` utilizando `item.id`.

Comment: Olá amigo, é mais ou menos isso que eu queria mesmo,eu possuo o `Avaliacao` `belongs_to :item`. Fiz alguns testes e observei que apenas itens **com** avaliações foram retornados e que não houve diferenciação entre avaliações negativas e positivas, vou editar a pergunta para colocar um exemplo.

Comment: Entendi, vou editar minha reposta.

Answer (score 0):

A base é uma query com `JOIN` entre as duas tabelas. É preciso também agrupar por item, e ordenar pela soma das avaliações:

```sql
SELECT Item.id, Item.nome, SUM(Avaliacao.avaliacao) AS positivos
FROM Item
INNER JOIN Avaliacao
ON Avaliacao.item_id = Item.id
GROUP BY Item.id
ORDER BY SUM(Avaliacao.avaliacao) DESC
```

Comment: Após responder, percebi que só havia a tag ruby-on-rails na pergunta... Se você quiser fazer isso com métodos do Rails, aí não sei.